# VB.NET 2013 - Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have been trying to make an auto complete using the inbuilt properties of textbox. Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=PROSOFT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=intellipos;User Id=sa;Password=Password1;"
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "select firstname from customer"
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Me.ds.Clear()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "list")
        conn.Close()
        Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("firstname").ToString())
        Next
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

    End Sub
End Class
```

But I am getting this error: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized at `ds.fill(da, "list")`

I am just a beginner in VB.NET and forgive me for any typing mistakes.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not tell the SqlCommand which connection to use.

```
cmd.Connection = conn
```

But this is just repeating what the error already tells you.

Alternatively, create the Command from the connection:

```
Dim command As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
```

Answer (score 2):

To be more clear;

```
       conn.ConnectionString = "Server=PROSOFT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=intellipos;User Id=sa;Password=Password1;"
        conn.Open()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Me.ds.Clear()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select firstname from customer",conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "list")
        conn.Close()
```

would work. You do not have to declare `command` for such queries.

Comment: Thanks sir for your advice. I will keep this in mind for the next time